# Why can't java find StringEntity class even after importing org.apache.http packages?

Tags: java, apache, api

I am using a  sample code from Microsoft Cognitive Services. It makes use of StringEntity class to make request to the REST API. The java compiler seems to be unable to find 'symbol' StringEntity? What could be the reason for this and how to resolve this? 
Here goes the code -

```
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.http.*;


public class NEWS_FETCHER 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        try
        {
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search");

            builder.setParameter("q", "microsoft");
            builder.setParameter("count", "10");
            builder.setParameter("offset", "0");
            builder.setParameter("mkt", "en-us");
            builder.setParameter("safeSearch", "Moderate");

            URI uri = builder.build();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "<Key goes here>");

            // Request body
            StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("");
            request.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Most of it is taken from Microsoft API Test Sample.
https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f72cf5ff8098cef380a/operations/56b449fbcf5ff81038d15cdf

Comment: did you import the jar? Are you using maven? or did you import the jar manually?

Comment: if you are using maven or gradle please update the project.seems like jar is not properly inside the buildpath.

Comment: @Rajith Pemabandu  , rest non of the classes required show any error, only StringEntity shows so I suppose problem is not with the imports. I was wondering in what package string entity placed? I imported the whole import org.apache.http.*;package but it still did not work.

Comment: here it is .https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html

Answer (score 4):

The class `StringEntity` is in the package `org.apache.http.entity`, so you have to add the correct import for that:

```
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
```

Comment: does `import org.apache.http.*`; does not contain this import?

Comment: No. Subpackages are not automatically imported.